# run-time error '381': occurs when I add an item into a listbox after removing an item

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, listboxitem

This is the code that populated the listbox, taking most of the data from TextBoxes.

iListCount is Declared as global. For reasons unknown to me the list box only populates the first line and wouldn't take subsequent ones unless done that way.

```
 Private Sub cmdAddFraudCharges_Click()
    With Me.lstFCHRGS '<- ListBox        
        .ColumnCount = 6
        .ColumnWidths = "60;65;50;26;35;70"
        .AddItem
        .List(iListCount, 0) = dtpAddDt |<--DateTimePicker|error occurs here
        .List(iListCount, 1) = txtAddAmt |<--Continues till last column
        iListCount = iListCount + 1
    End With        
End Sub
```

Here's the code I used to simultaneously delete the listbox item and the worksheet entry.

```
Private Sub cmdDelChrgs_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim t As Integer

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = wksFraud.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    Set wksFraud = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fraud")

    For iListCount = lstFCHRGS.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        x = lstFCHRGS.ListCount
        If lstFCHRGS.Selected(iListCount) Then
            y = iListCount
            t = (x - y) - 1

            With rngTarget
                Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(-t, 0)
                rngTarget.EntireRow.Delete
            End With

            lstFCHRGS.RemoveItem (iListCount)
        End If
    Next iListCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting `i` prior to adding the new item?  (But, if your first block of code immediately follows your second block of code, then `i` has a value of `-1` so that would explain the error.)

Comment: @YowE3k you're exactly right, is there a way to work around this, like reset (i) or something to avoid the error? I'm new to coding and this is actually my first attempt at it. I could post the entire code, I'm just not sure if it's ok to do so... If it's ok I'd gladly post the whole code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to post enough that we can see how `i` is being set to an invalid value (probably -1) when it gets to the `.List(i, 0) = txt1` line.  I am scared about how much code is "the whole code" - if it is only a couple of hundred lines, post it and we can edit it down to the relevant parts afterwards.  If it is more than that, you will need to do some editing yourself to get rid of stuff that is definitely not related to how `i` is getting its value.

Comment: @YowE3K got rid of most of the stuff that didn't affect (i) which was really called iListCount. The first chunk adds the items to the list box and also adds the data to the worksheet. Will basically manipulate the list box items while they're stored in memory and on the next transaction it doesn't have to be in the listbox so I kept a copy on the worksheet. I gave (me) the user the tool to delete items (though one at a time), then when I click on add new item the error occurs. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this one. Cheers!

Comment: @MarkVincentManansala Is `iListCount` a global? If so, it looks like it's going to be set to the (last + 1) index of the list after you delete. After `Next iListCount` you should reset it to zero.

Comment: @Rob WOW! thank you Rob, I will try that :)

Comment: @Rob That worked in the sense that an error no longer occurs. However, the ListBox wouldn't show the next item I add. The values calculated change accordingly but the newly added item would only show the TickBox to select the new item. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see how it's working, but perhaps it might be `iListCount = lstFCHRGS.ListCount - 1` instead of zero as I suggested before. In any case; this is a good demonstration of why it's usually a bad idea to use global variables like this. `iListCount` should really be a local variable

Comment: @Rob thank you for the idea. You've helped me solve the issue and it now works perfectly. So I added a bunch of MsgBox to show how iListCount is changing and edited a few lines to make it work. :) changed for i with |For iListCount = LBound(lstFCHRGS.List) To UBound(lstFCHRGS.List|<-- this caused the value to become 0 then as I stepped through it went back to it's original number then added 1 so I added iListCount = iListCount -1 after delete to restore the value of iListCount after deleting an entry. It now works perfectly. Thank you Rob and YowE3k for your help. Cheers!

Comment: @MarkVincentManansala Glad you got it working! Would you be able to write your solution up as an answer here and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Rob will do, just saw the answer question button :) Thank you Rob, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Rob, tried my best to make the answer coherent. lol hope that works! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> After adding 5 items to the list iListCount would be equal to 4. due
>   to this line iListCount = iListCount + 1 it would now be equal to 5.

Private Sub cmdDelChrgs_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim t As Integer

```
Dim rngTarget As Range
Set rngTarget = wksFraud.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set wksFraud = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fraud")

'For iListCount = lstFCHRGS.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1|<-- changed this with 
For iListCount = LBound(lstFCHRGS.List) To UBound(lstFCHRGS.List)
```

> iListCount=0 at this point
>   as it loops iListCount would have the value of 5

```
    If lstFCHRGS.Selected(iListCount) Then
        x = lstFCHRGS.ListCount
        y = iListCount
        t = (x - y) - 1

        With rngTarget
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(-t, 0)
            rngTarget.EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        lstFCHRGS.RemoveItem (iListCount)
End If
Next iListCount
```

> After deleting the item iListCount is still 5 and was probably the cause of the error

```
iListCount = iListCount - 1|<-- Add  after next to restores the value of iListCount
```

Comment: In a `For iListCount = 0 To 4` loop, the `Next iListCount` increments the value of `iListCount` so, when it was 3 it increments to 4 and decides "OK, I can still go through the loop again" but when it is 4 it increments to 5 and says "Hmmm, 5 is greater than the end value of 4, I don't need to process any more".  So then code continues after the `Next` **but `iListCount` is 5**.  You really should only use loop counters **within the loop** - never use them again outside.  (Some future version of VBA might change the current behaviour and cause you untold misery fixing your code up.)